# Ampersand conflict in LESS and SASS compilers

Tags: sass, less, ampersand

I'm converting some LESS to SASS and I'm currently getting an error due to this block of code

```
.navbar{
    &-inverse {
        .brand:hover {
            color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of LESS is causing me a SASS error:

```
Invalid CSS after " &": expected "{", was "-inverse {"
"-inverse" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

In both languages,`&` is just a placeholder for the parent of the current level of nesting (so in this case `.navbar`), so what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

In Sass `&` only works with a child/parent/adjacent selector (space, `>`, `+`, `~`, ... where it is ignored, if in front, or adds the parent after another selector) or to add a **class** (starting with a `.`), an **id** (starting with `#`) or a **pseudo-selector** (starting with `:`).

The functionality you want is not implemented yet, but it is planned for v3.3. You can read a bit [more here](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286#issuecomment-17728080).

You could for example design a mixin that appends something to a selector.
Maybe something in this direction:

```
@mixin inverse($selector){
    #{$selector}-inverse {
        .brand:hover {
            color: black;
        }
    }
}

@include inverse(".navbar");
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's not exactly the perfect answer I've got a solution that you might consider using.

```
.navbar {
    &[class*="-inverse"] {
        .brand:hover {
            color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

The "[class*=-inverse"]" means "if the class has '-inverse' in it", so in addition with ".navbar" it looks like this: .navbar[class*="-inverse"] which essentially is this ".navbar-inverse" which is what you're trying to do.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although it passed some time from the question, I've found the same problem. 
My solution was to update SASS (3.2) to the latest version (3.3.3). 
In fact, there was an open issue which temporarily suspended support for this feature.

Link to the issue on github:
https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286

Hope it helps.